# How to limit notifications on an node edition to some specific nodes?

Tags: notifications

I'm using the [Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) module Notifications 7.x-1.0-alpha2 on Drupal 7

I'd like to have notifications allowed only on some specific nodes (for examples, node/1 and node/3).
The module has a "content type" notification, which sends mails each times a change is made on any node of that content type.

But I'd like to have those notifications only on some specific nodes(for examples, node/1 and node/3), and I can't find out how to do that with the [Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) module.

As I'm already using that module on our Forum, it would be best not to have to use another module, also.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens 
You're right, my question wasn't really clear.
Hope that it is, now.

Comment: OK, "much" more clear now. Hopefully you'll get answers that will help you. However, as per the "... not to have to use another module ..." you added, I won't post a possible answer with an alternative I would recommend you to look at, i.e. a variation of my answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179403/how-to-allow-registered-users-to-enable-disable-notifications-for-event-nodes/179409#179409 ... Let me know if you ever want to consider other modules anyway.

Comment: I'd like to "not have to" but sometimes, you have to :)
The fact is that as we're already using in production Notifications with it's forum extension, we tend to stay on Notifications.
Do you know if the Message module should work also with Advanced Forum, wih is our Forum module ?